# Webservice provider in Domino spikes CPU and cause semaphore lock state

Tags: xml, web-services, http, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have created a simple webservice provider in Domino, it looks something like this:

```
Public Class Integration

    Sub New
        Set session = New NotesSession
        Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    End Sub

    Public Function importA() 
        importA = getData()
    End Function

End Class
```

We have created an external webservice consumer that uses functions in the provider to both get and send data.

My problem is that when sending or receiving xml files (about 2mb in size) the Domino spikes cpu to 100% and Domino console sometimes indicate Semaphore lock states. just loading or sending the xml file takes about 11 minutes.

When receiving xml files we get them as a string parameter in the function, when sending xml files we send them as a string from the function.

What could be the cause of this delay and lock on the domino server?

We are running in a local LAN and have no internet connection problems, The Domino server is not busy doing any other tasks.

Comment: This sounds like an issue for IBM support.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pointers you might want to look at:

- A webservice should go and send XML, not Strings that look like XML. You might want to create a proper WSDL description that matches your XML structure. That will speed up processing quite a bit. Use the SAX to write the XML.
- Verse (and FP8) improved greatly on Semaphore locks, that might help too (the improvement is part of the hotfixes released for Verse, and will be in Fp8 too)
- When you create your 2MB String... do you use String concatenation or a NotesStream. The stream would be much preferable
- Finally, you might want to try to rewrite the code in Java - better to profile. Use SAX to [write the document](http://notessensei.com/blog/2010/11/oracle-broke-the-java-forums-%23fail-and-how-to-use-sax-to-create-xml-documents-in-java.html) or use [my helper class](http://notessensei.com/blog/downloads/2011/SimpleXMLDoc.java)

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks. I ditched the webservice and instead I save the xml files to  notesdocuments from a post request. much faster.